# Empty list in case of absense in request - SpringBoot and Jackson

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I have the following class:

```
class A {
    List <Integer> l;
    int a;
}
```

Now, when user sends request:

```
{
    a: 11,
}
```

it deserializes to `A.a=11, A.l=null`.

I would like to in case of `null` send list it deserializes to empty list.

Can I do it in some elegant way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need add default value in l property

```
class A {
  List <Integer> l = = new ArrayList<>();
  int a;
}
```